# Transform strings in one column to multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, plyr

My dataset looks like below:

```
"Fruit","Allocation"

apple,Anna:1|Bob:2|Chloe:3

banana,Anna:3|Bob:2|Chloe:1
```

I want to transform it to look like below instead:

```
"Fruit","Anna","Bob","Chloe"

apple,1,2,3

banana,3,2,1
```

What is the easiest way to transform my dataset to look like my desired output in **R**?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `tidyverse`.  Use `separate_rows` to convert from 'wide' to 'long' by splitting the 'Allocation' column at `|`, then `separate` the 'Allocation' column into two columns 'Name', 'Number' at `sep=":"` and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df1, Allocation, sep="[|]") %>%
        separate(Allocation, into = c("Name", "Number")) %>%
        spread(Name, Number)
#   Fruit Anna Bob Chloe
#1  apple    1   2     3
#2 banana    3   2     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Fruit = c("apple", "banana"), Allocation = c("Anna:1|Bob:2|Chloe:3", 
"Anna:3|Bob:2|Chloe:1")), .Names = c("Fruit", "Allocation"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```